# How to go to a parent node from a node in a treeview of wijmo flex grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, wijmo

I am using wijmo flex grid to create a tree view for my data, I am able to find whether a specific node has children or not and what is the level of the node but I am unable to go to the parent node from a given node. The index for each row is also being retrieved.

Any insights on the topic would be highly helpful.

```
$scope.selectionChanged = function(sender,args){
       var index = sender.selection.row;
        var temp;
        console.log(index);
        temp = sender._rows[index]._data;
        console.log(temp.reports);
    };
```

Comment: Please post your detail code, it will be helpful for us to answer your question

Comment: I am using selectionChanged method to detect a click on a row.. this method receives two arguments -[sender, args]
the sender object has got the details of the entire grid using which I am able to retrieve the row index , level in the hierarchy, info whether the node has children or not.. 
now what i need to do is given a child node a need to identify its parent node..

Comment: Edited .posted the code in the question. @KhalidHussain ..

Answer (score 1):

FlexGrid rows come in two flavors: regular rows (Row objects) and nodes (GroupRow objects). Regular rows have no "level", but GroupRow objects do have a "level" property that you can use to get the node's level.

To get a row's parent node, you should scan the grid's rows collection up until you find a node that has a "level" smaller than the one you started with.

Here's a fiddle the demonstrates:

http://jsfiddle.net/Wijmo5/8n2yde6f/

Check out the implementation of the "getParentNode" method, that should be what you're looking for:

```
// gets the parent row for a given FlexGrid row.
// returns the parent row or null if original row doesn't have a parent.
function getParentNode(row) {

  // get row level
  var startLevel = row instanceof(wijmo.grid.GroupRow) ? row.level : -1;
  var startIndex = row.index;

  // travel up to find parent node
  for (var i = startIndex - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var thisRow = row.grid.rows[i],
        thisLevel = thisRow instanceof(wijmo.grid.GroupRow) ? thisRow.level : -1;
    if (thisLevel > -1) {
      if (startLevel == -1 || (startLevel > -1 && thisLevel < startLevel)) {
        return thisRow;
      }
    }
  }

  // not found
  return null;
};
```

Hope this is useful.

Comment: Thanks, Bernardo. I misread the question and gave a useless answer... Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is access the dataItem of the selected row and see if it contains children, using the FlexGrid's childItemPath that you set.

Here is a working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/banzor/700e6bn2/1/

And here is the code for my selectionChanged event.

```
$scope.selectionChanged = function(sender, args){
    var index = args.row;
    var row = args.panel.rows[index].dataItem;
    var childPath = sender.childItemsPath;
    var children = row[childPath];

    if (children && wijmo.isArray(children)) {
        console.log("Has items: " + children.length);
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your response guys.. got what I wanted.